# How do I read a Hiera value from a Puppet function?

Tags: ruby, puppet, hiera

I have to write a function that will, in order, perform the following to read the value of a variable:

- Check if there is a facter variable defined. If not,
- Read the value of the variable from Hiera. If not,
- Use a default value.

I have managed to do it in my Puppet script using this if condition.

```
  # foo is read from (in order of preference): facter fact, hiera hash, hard coded value
  if $::foo == undef {
     $foo = hiera('foo', 'default_value')
  } else {
     $foo = $::foo
  }
```

But I want to avoid repeating this if condition for each variable I wish to parse in this manner, and therefore thought of writing a new Puppet function of the format `get_args('foo', 'default_value')` which will return me the value from

1. a facter fact if it exists,
2. a hiera variable, or
3. just return `default_value`.

I know that I can use `lookupvar` to read a facter fact from a ruby function. How do I read a hiera variable from my Puppet ruby function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call defined functions using the `function_` prefix.

You have found the `lookupvar` function already.

Putting it all together:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:get_args, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
    # retrieve variable with the name of the first argument
    variable_value = lookupvar(args[0])
    return variable_value if !variable_value.nil?
    # otherwise, defer to the hiera function
    function_hiera(args)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Felix, that's very useful. However, when doing this, I get a different error. 

I have a second argument I need to pass to the function (the default value), and when I do that like so

    class myclass($foo=get_args('foo', 'monkeypatch')) {
    }

I then get an error saying, "custom functions must be called with a single array that contains the arguments". I am running Puppet 3.6.2 with Ruby 1.8.7.

This is probably a separate SO question.

Comment: Weird. Works For Me: `puppet apply -e '$foo = "bar" $bar = get_args("foobar","default") notify { $bar: }'` - Raises no exception, output is 'default'.

Comment: Felix, it was because instead of calling ``function_hiera(args)``, I was calling ``function_hiera(args[0], args[1])``. The stacktrace was spectacularly useless; which is whY I couldn't figure out it was my Ruby code that was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: FWIW, new Puppet 4.x convention is `call_function('hiera', *args)`. ([ref1](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/puppet-users/155pjs9cm3/calling-hiera-functions-from-inside-ruby-templates-broken-in-puppet-4-x), [ref2](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/yard/Puppet/Pops/Functions/Function.html#call_function-instance_method))